# delete database android sqlite

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I want to create a logout button which will drop the entire database and finishes the current activity and redirect to the LoginActivity.

This does work but I need to restart my application to commit the changes.
For example, when the app goes back to the LoginActivity it will still see the user data. If I restart the app it will show me the login form as it should be.
How can i accomplish this?

Globals.java

```
public void signOff(){

    SharedPreferences preferences =  instance.context.getSharedPreferences("globals", 0);
    preferences.edit().remove("domain").commit();

    DatabaseHelper dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(instance.context);
    dbHelper.deleteData();


    finish();
    Intent mainActivity = new Intent(instance.context, LoginActivity.class);
    instance.context.startActivity(mainActivity);
}
```

DatabaseHelper.java

```
public final class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

   public SQLiteDatabase db;

   public static DatabaseHelper instance ;
   public static Context context;
   public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Oryx.db";
   public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

   public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
       super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

       // Init the singleton
       if (instance == null){
           instance = this;
           instance.context = context;
           instance.db = instance.getWritableDatabase();
       }
   }

   public DatabaseHelper(Context context, String tableCreateQuery)
   {
       this(context);
       instance.db.execSQL(tableCreateQuery);
   }

   @Override
   public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
   }

   @Override
   public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

   }

   public void deleteData(){
       instance.context.deleteDatabase(DATABASE_NAME);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write method in **DatabaseHelper** class where you have extended **SQLiteOpenHelper** class

```
/**
 * Delete database
 */
public static void deleteDatabase(Context mContext) {
    mContext.deleteDatabase(DATABASE_NAME);
}
```

then you can call directly like `DatabaseHelper.deleteDatabase(mContext);`

Thank you.

Comment: Nice practice but this didn't do the trick yet. Same result but i'll keep this method since it's much cleaner calling it static.

Answer (score 1):

Turned out I had to close the database and set the instance to null. In combination with the answer Pratik supplied it works.

```
   public static void closeDatabase(){
       instance.db.close();
       instance = null;
   }

   public static void deleteDatabase(Context mContext){
       mContext.deleteDatabase(DATABASE_NAME);
   }
```

Answer (score -1):

replace finish(); with finishAffinity(); 
or you can also try

```
mainActivity .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                            mainActivity .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
```

for deleteing database use folling method

```
public void clearDate()
    {
        try {
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

            db.delete(DATABASE_NAME, null, null);

            db.close(); // Closing database connection
        } catch (SQLiteException ex) {
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the addFlags tho, helped me a little :) !

Comment: This is not a good idea. getWritableDatabase may raise an exception if the database is corrupted. It is better to delete the database through a solid mechanism that is not subject to such exceptions.